# Javascript Regex for colon?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wondering how I can use javascript regex to match a word like:

`Name:`

with all variations of spaces ? This is where I'm getting stuck. i.e.

- `Name<space>: Fred`
- `Name:<space>Fred` or `Name<space>:<space>Fred`

Note the positioning of the spaces after the name, after the colon etc ?

I was hoping something like `/(name(\s*:\s*)?)\w/g` would work but it doesn't :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Name starts with a capital letter. The regex should also match name starting with a capital N.

  - If you want the entire regex to be case insensitive, add the `i` flag at the end.
  - If you only want name to start with a lower or upper case N, then use a set
- The `*` means 0 or more. The `?` is not needed anymore.

Something like this should work

```
/Name\s*:\s*\w*/g    //matches "Name"

/[Nn]ame\s*:\s*\w*/g //matches "Name" or "name"

/name\s*:\s*\w*/gi   //the entire regex is case insensitive
```

Comment: thanks heaps :) what if the `:` was optional in some places ?  i.e. so its like `Name Fred` how would i also handle that ?

Comment: you mean like `/(name\s*:?\s*)\w/gi` ?

Comment: @Andy yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

regex `/name\s*:\s*\w/gi` is enough.

Comment: you mean `/gi` <-- case-insensitive